# Copy and paste only path in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I have a shape with many effects applied to it like shadow, stroke, color etc. I want to copy only the path of this shape and use it for different illustrator project.

Obviously I can delete all the effects and then copy paste the object but I'm looking for some other ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy, Paste, then with the object selected, choose `Clear Appearance` or `Reduce to Basic Appearance` from the **Appearance Panel** menu.

Or with the object selected, click the `Default` style in the **Graphic Styles Panel**. (This is the same as choosing `Reduce to Basic Appearance` but its just 1 click away)